# ID issues after form_for [@user, @employeur] with nested and singular resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested, has-one

I have an issue with a form since after entering the data, I get `Couldn't find Employeur without an ID` when my show method is called. I think it is due to my nested resources.

Here are my routes:

```
resources :users do
  resource: employeur
  resource: prestataire
end
```

My user controller, that sends me right to the employeur form once the user one has been filled:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

#TODO index user doit être suprimé quand inutile pour dev
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        if params[:commit] == 'Prestataire'
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_prestataire_path(user_id: @user), notice: "Renseignez vos informations d'employeur" }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
        else 
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_employeur_path(user_id: @user), notice: "Renseignez vos informations de prestataire" }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        if params[:commit] == 'Prestataire'
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_prestataire_path(user_id: @user), notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        else 
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_employeur_path(user_id: @user), notice: "User was successfully updated." }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :surname, :forename, :civility, :phone)
  end

end
```

My employeur form with which I'm in trouble:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @employeur] do |f| %>
  <% if @employeur.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@employeur.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this employeur from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @employeur.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :siren, 'Siren: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :siren %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :societe, 'Société: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :societe %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :code_postal, 'Code Postal: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :code_postal %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And my employeur controller which can't find my employeur params:

```
class EmployeursController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_user

  def index
    @employeurs = @user.employeur.all
  end


  def show
    @employeur = Employeur.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @employeur = @user.build_employeur
  end

  def edit
    @employeur = Employeur.find(params[:id])
  end


  def create
    @employeur = @user.build_employeur(employeur_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employeur.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@user, @employeur], notice: 'Employeur was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @employeur }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @employeur.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
  @employeur = Employeur.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employeur.update_attributes(employeur_params)
        format.html { redirect_to [@user, @employeur], notice: 'Employeur was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @employeur }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @employeur.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


def destroy
  @employeur = Employeur.find(params[:id])
  @employeur.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @user }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  def load_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def employeur_params
    params.require(:employeur).permit(:siren, :societe, :code_postal)
  end

end
```

I've decided to edit my first post to add all my routes linked to employeurs that @Sirius ROR:

```
   user_employeur POST   /users/:user_id/employeur(.:format)              em
```

ployeurs#create
   new_user_employeur GET    /users/:user_id/employeur/new(.:format)          em
ployeurs#new
  edit_user_employeur GET    /users/:user_id/employeur/edit(.:format)         em
ployeurs#edit
                      GET    /users/:user_id/employeur(.:format)              em
ployeurs#show
                      PATCH  /users/:user_id/employeur(.:format)              em
ployeurs#update
                      PUT    /users/:user_id/employeur(.:format)              em
ployeurs#update
                      DELETE /users/:user_id/employeur(.:format)              em
ployeurs#destroy

I've also made a significant change:

Became:

Because I've made a signifant change on my Employeur Model:

```
class Employeur < ActiveRecord::Base
  model_name.instance_variable_set :@route_key, 'employeur'
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :projets, as: :projetable
  has_many :prestataires, through: :projets
  has_many :offres, through: :projets
  has_many :feedbacks, through: :projets
  validates :siren, :societe, :code_postal, presence: true
end
```

According to what I've eventually found on internet, the first line deals with the url issue. Despite this change, I still get the exact same error: Couldn't find Employeur without an ID.

Here is also my User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :prestataire
  has_one :employeur
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employeur, allow_destroy: true
  has_secure_password
end
```

Comment: So, you are trying to create employer? And looks like it is trying to update it.

Comment: I've read that this is a common issue with rails regarding the Orcid Rails engine and that pixeltrix is working on it. I've also found that I should replace form_for [@user, @employeur], url: user_employeur_path -- by -- form_for[@employeur, :url => user_employeur_path(@user)]. Yet, it didn't work for me.

Comment: Great, you should post an answer for future generations=:)

Comment: I've read it somewhere, but I'm not sure it works. I've tested this and it doesn't work for me so... Maybe I should adapt my employeur controller. I don't know.

Comment: @zishe and Himesh, something really weird happens. The only two params that pass after the form_for of [@user, @employeur] are user_id and format. I've therefore substituted the :id by :format in my employeur controller. And the redirection worked! Yet, my url is then http://localhost:3000/users/179/employeur.64 . And I can't get in my show views the employeur params like siren, societe or code_postal. Maybe this can help you understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing url option from form_for as form for automatically builds the post url

```
<%= form_for [@user, @employeur] do |f| %>
```

This must work well.

Comment: Unfortnuately, not for a nested resource, with has_one. This form_for will generate a user_employeurs_path, which doesn't exist since I have these routes: resources :users do resource: employeur end.

Comment: Ok. Can you provide me with the output of "rake routes | grep employeur" command.